# Is it possible perform a fulltext search on MySQL 8.0, with double quotes and wildcard?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mysql-8.0

Based on past answers, I see that it was previously possible to perform fulltext searches with double quotes and wildcard, like the following:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable MATCH (mycolumn) AGAINST ('"myemail@gma"*');
```

however, when I try this on the latest MySQL version(s), 8.0.25, I get an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'
```

Is there any way to make this type of search work?

The only alternative I can see, in the email case, is to search the terms separated, with an AND condition (e.g. '+myemail +gma*', assuming stopwords disabled), but the semantics of the search are different.

Comment: It seems due to use single and double quotes surrounding the text. If you remove the first or last double-quote, works fine. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cff69fe745ac3b02cf97af3ee313788

Comment: Double quotes are semantically meaningful in fulltext searches; they can't be "just removed".

Comment: Try `('"myemail gma"*')` and `("myemail@gma"*)`

Comment: Still get an error (on 8.0.25): `mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE MATCH (str) AGAINST ('"myemail gma"*');
ERROR 1064 (42000): syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'`
and `mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE MATCH (str) AGAINST ('"myemail@gma"*');
ERROR 1064 (42000): syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'`

Answer (score 0):

It is not longer supported to add a wildcard at the end of a phrase. But You can use subQuery flow in order to improve the performance. First use MATCH(mycolumn) against ('"myemail@gma"'). This will be the subQuery and the outerQuery will perform the like 'myemail@gma%' for the SubQuery returned records.

Comment: Hi Jai, you could improve your answer by giving an example to clarify your explanation.